# Constructing Young tableaux basic question

Tags: lie-algebras, young-tableaux

I'm trying to understand Young tableaux and was making some exercises.

I'm a bit confused with the following question
Given a tensor $B^{ijk}$ where $B^{ijk} = -B^{jik}$ and $B^{ijk} + B^{kij} + B^{jki} = 0$, draw the Young tableau.

I can see that the first two indices are anti-symmetric from the first condition, but I'm confused on the second. It seems to me that it says that the tensor is symmetric with respect to interchange of the first and last indices as well as the second and third.

Comment: This document can maybe help you : http://www.phys.nthu.edu.tw/~class/group_theory2012fall/doc/tensor.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm still a bit confused, would this result in the 8th tableau in the middle on p6?

Comment: Frankly, I cannot say yes or no because I am not sure to fully be "mentally" in phase with the used vocabulary

Comment: Thanks for the reference anyway!